# How to take input in this form in python?

Tags: python, arrays, input

So, I want to take input of the following -

```
3
1 2
2 4
3 4
```

The first line contains an integer n. Each of the following n lines contains a pair of distinct space-separated integers.
I want to store the inputs of first column in one array and the second column in another array.
I came up with this code, can you tell me where I went wrong and how to do it?

```
n = int(input())
h = []
g = []
num = 0
for i in range(n):
    m = map(int,input().split("\n"))
    h.append(m)
for j in range(n): 
    ni = map(int,input().split("\n"))
    h.append(ni)
```

Comment: So do you want [3,1,2,3]  in Array1 and [2,4,4] in Array2? Or is the first integer omitted?

Comment: No ,I wanted [1,2,3] in one array and [2,4,4] in another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read using [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) you get the entire current line of input as a string, so each of your calls to `input` after the first will return `'1 2'`, `'2 4'` and finally `'3 4'`.

You need to split those strings on   (space) and then convert the values to integers and append them to the `h` and `g` lists. For example:

```
for i in range(n):
    this_h, this_g = map(int, input().split(' '))
    h.append(this_h)
    g.append(this_g)
print(h)
print(g)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 4]
```